# example of a DSL generated copyArtifacts job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to use DSL to generate a job that uses `copyArtifacts`. I have been able to generate basic `Copy artifact from another project` using the following:

```
job('DSL-AgreegateArtifacts') {
  steps {
    copyArtifacts( 'Template-DSPL_RPub' )
  }
}
```

However I also need to be able to specify `Which build`, `Artifacts to copy` and `Target directory`. It is not clear to me how I use `Closure copyArtifactClosure` to specify this information? I have not found any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in the Job DSL reference for [copyArtifacts](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#copy-artifacts):

```
job('example') {
    steps {
        copyArtifacts('upstream') {
            includePatterns('*.xml', '*.properties')
            targetDirectory('files')
            buildSelector {
                latestSuccessful(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```